# PHP PDO connection with MS SQL Server using ODBC

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, pdo

I have a db.php file & and init.php to use within my register.php file.

I have a database within MS SQL Server and am trying to connect to it using PDO.

This error is showing and I can't see why. I used the same code to connect to a MySQL db and this inserted the record as should, but doesn't when writing to a MSSQLServer

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not
>   find driver' in C:\ooplr\classes\DB.php:14 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\ooplr\classes\DB.php(14):
>   PDO->__construct('mssql:host=myserver;...', 'username', 'pwd') #1
>   C:\ooplr\classes\DB.php(23): DB->__construct() #2
>   C:\ooplr\classes\Validate.php(8): DB::getInstance() #3
>   C:\ooplr\register.php(9): Validate->__construct() #4 {main} thrown in
>   C:\ooplr\classes\DB.php on line 14

**The db.php page**

```
<?php
    class DB {
public static $instance = null;
private     $_pdo = null,
            $_query = null,
            $_error = false,
            $_results = null,
            $_count = 0;
private function __construct() {
    try {           
        $this->_pdo = new PDO('mssql:host=' . Config::get('mssql/server') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mssql/db'), Config::get('mssql/username'), Config::get('mssql/password'));
    } catch(PDOExeption $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
public static function getInstance() {
    if(!isset(self::$instance)) {
        self::$instance = new DB();
    }
    return self::$instance;
}
public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
    $this->_error = false;
    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $x = 1;
        if(count($params)) {
            foreach($params as $param) {
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }
        if($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        } else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }       
    return $this;
}
public function get($table, $where) {
return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
}
public function delete($table, $where) {
    return $this->action('DELETE', $table, $where);
}
public function action($action, $table, $where = array()) {
    if(count($where) === 3) {
        $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');
        $field      = $where[0];
        $operator   = $where[1];
        $value      = $where[2];
        if(in_array($operator, $operators)) {
            $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator}   ?";
            if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {
                return $this;
            }
        }           
        return false;
    }
}
public function insert($table, $fields = array()) {
    $keys   = array_keys($fields);
    $values = null;
    $x      = 1;
    foreach($fields as $value) {
        $values .= "?";
        if($x < count($fields)) {
            $values .= ', ';
        }
        $x++;
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} (`" . implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) VALUES     ({$values})";
    if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public function update($table, $id, $fields = array()) {
    $set    = null;
    $x      = 1;
    foreach($fields as $name => $value) {
        $set .= "{$name} = ?";
        if($x < count($fields)) {
            $set .= ', ';
        }
        $x++;
    }
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET {$set} WHERE id = {$id}";
    if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public function results() {
    return $this->_results;
}
public function first() {
    return $this->_results[0];
}
public function count() {
    return $this->_count;
}
public function error() {
    return $this->_error;
}}?>
```

**The init.php page**

```
  <?php
    session_start();
    $GLOBALS['config'] = array(
'mssql' => array(
    'server' => 'MyServer',
    'username'  => 'MyUsr',
    'password'  => 'Mypwd',
    'db'    => 'dbname'
),
'remember' => array(
    'cookie_name'   => 'hash',
    'cookie_expiry' =>  604800
),
'session' => array(
    'session_name'  => 'user',
    'token_name'    => 'token'
)
    );
    function autoload($class) {
require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
     }
    spl_autoload_register('autoload');
     require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';
    if(Cookie::exists(Config::get('remember/cookie_name'))) {
$hash = Cookie::get(Config::get('remember/cookie_name'));
$hashCheck = DB::getInstance()->get('users_session', array('hash', '=', $hash));
if($hashCheck->count()) {
    $user = new User($hashCheck->first()->user_id);
    $user->login();
}}?>
```

**The register.php page**

```
     <?php
     require 'core/init.php';
     error_reporting (E_ALL);
     ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
     if(Input::exists()) {
 if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {
    $validate = new Validate();
    $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
        'username' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 20,
            'unique' => 'users'),
        'password' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 6),
        'password_again' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'matches' => 'password'),
        'name' => array(
            'required' => false,
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 50)
    ));
    if($validation->passed()) {
        $user = new User();
        $salt = Hash::salt(32);
        try {
            $user->create(array(
                'username'  => Input::get('username'),
                'password'  =>   Hash::make(Input::get('password'), $salt),
                'salt'      => $salt,
                'name'      => Input::get('name'),
                'joined'    => getdate(),
                'group'     => 1
            ));
            Session::flash('home', 'You have been registered and can now log in!');
            Redirect::to('index.php');
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        foreach($validate->errors() as $error) {
            echo $error, '<br>';
        }}}}?>

     <form action="" method="post">

<div class="field">
    <label for="username">Choose a username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo  escape(Input::get('username')); ?>">
</div>

<div class="field">
    <label for="password">Choose a password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
</div>

<div class="field">
    <label for="password_again">Enter your password again</label>
    <input type="password" name="password_again" id="password_again">
</div>

<div class="field">
    <label for="name">Your name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('name')); ?>">
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Register">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
    </form>
```

How can I get this to connect and send the data?

Comment: `PDO` hasn't got the driver for `mssql`. [please see the manual on how to install it](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php).

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to get it to connect :-) I'm looking at the hash issue I have now!

Answer (score 0):

You error message says that PHP/PDO could not find a driver for SQL Server.
This happens because [PDO does not support SQL Server drivers](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php) out of the box.

To get SQL Server support you will need to add [Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098) to your PHP installation. This will only be possible if you have control over the PHP installation on the server (this is possible on a local server but not possible in a shared hosting environment).

Alternatively, you may consider using [PHP's MSSQL Database Extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php) that does support Microsoft SQL Server. CodeIgniter uses the MSSQL database extension in their [MSSQL database driver](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/drivers/mssql/mssql_driver.php).